# Lumen 5.3: Set php artisan environment

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

How can I set environment variable of a php artisan command using Lumen 5.3? Laravel 5.0 says:

```
php artisan migrate --env=local
```

But in newer version documentations this section is disappeared. I run this my command like:

```
php artisan myCommand --env=testing
```

But both in my command class and bootstrap file (simply everywhere) dumping `env(APP_ENV)` results in `local`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you just trying to change the environment or are you trying to run a command as a specific environment, different to the one that is in your `.env` file?

Comment: I wanted to run a command in a specific environment different from what I have in .env file. @Alfa solution works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as simple as

```
APP_ENV="production" php artisan myCommand
```

Or in multiple environment as

```
APP_ENV="production" DB_USER="foo" DB_PASSWORD="bar" php artisan myCommand
```

Comment: Wow do I appreciate this (old) answer. You just saved me a ton of time -- thank you!!